# How should i add quality selector to react native video?

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I have created the **video player** with react-native-video, but now i have to add a quality selector to that player,how should i do that.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue. Please post your answer if you find any, this will help alot of developers.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video#selectedvideotrack

In the documentation there is resolution value, you can change it manually by creating a simple function and assigning the value to it.

```
 selectedVideoTrack={{
  type: "resolution",
  value: 480
}}
```

Comment: but to change the resolution we should have ui to select the quality.

Comment: i have same problem for get hls file quality  from url

Comment: `selectedVideoTrack` not working for me.